# What to put in Coverage Band Details in Mosaic definition

Tags: geoserver

The last part of the page when creating a Mosaic is a table called Coverage Band Details. As I understand it, it displays the bands in the existing files(s), but also gives me the chance to change some values. I can not find any documentation on this.

The problem is that Geoserver crashes when I try to save the mosaic when using the pre-filled values so I have to know what to write instead.

[image]

With the error message (removed a bunch of lines for readability):

```
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onRequest of interface org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener targeted at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.form.AjaxSubmitLink$1@7780dfd1 on component [GeoserverAjaxSubmitLink [Component id = apply]] threw an exception
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Character I is neither a decimal digit number, decimal point, nor "e" notation exponential mark.
    at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:586)
    at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:471)
    at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:900)
```

Where the essence of the message seems to be that it can not parse something as number. So I tried to remove the *minRange* and *maxRange* inifinity characters and it works! As the data type has been identified as unsigned char I guess that min=0 and max = 255 would suffice and give me no data loss.

Tested with Geoserver 2.22.1 and 2.24.2 with OpenJdk 8, 11 and 17. Same result. But if using oracle java 8 it works. As Geoserver 2.24 no longer supports (or even starts) with java 8 this is no longer an option. Haven't tested newer oracle java as we're taking the open source path.

Is the purpose of the table that I can change what data I would like to have interpreted as `null` or the other way around `null` is interpreted as 0. Can I filter the range of data from min to max and have everything outside that interval as `null`? And what about Unit? Can I change it? To what?